# Copy database file to local storage

Tags: android, sqlite, local-storage

I have a sqlite database in assete folder.

I want copy this to local storage.

I use this code,it copy database without tables. when i want to open database in sqlliteeditor, i get error 14.

```
  private void copyDataBase2() throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(  "/data/data/pakagename/Learning.db");
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("databases/Learning.db");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    is.close();
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the DB file like this:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = new File(getFilesDir(), "databases").getPath();
    private static String DB_NAME = "test_db.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private final Context fContext;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.fContext = context;
    }
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            //ничего не делаем – файл базы данных уже есть
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            //файл базы данных отсутствует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream input = fContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (dataBase != null)
            dataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

If you use API 19 or higher:

```
String db_path = fContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
```

> When i want to open database in sqlliteeditor, i get error 14.

Also I advise you to check the DB file. If an error occurs when you open it in the editor, it is likely that the problem is not in the file copy algorithm.

Comment: @ar.gorgin, also I advise you to check the DB file. If an error occurs when you open it in the editor, it is likely that the problem is not in the file copy algorithm.

Comment: when i open with navicat, it don't have error. with this code, copy database without tables

Comment: Don't hardcode the "/data/data/com.example.dbreadytest/databases/" thing. It can change in multi-user or container environment. Use `new File(getFilesDir(), "databases").getPath()` or something.

Comment: thanks, when  use it, i get error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/'domain name'/files/databases/Learning.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Answer (score 0):

It's just file copying, it does not matters it's a database or what. Actually the code above is not aware about tables and therefore has no ability to copy database without tables.

You can compare hashcodes of the two db files. To do so, you can change your code to copy the file to external storage instead of your app's data directory *for now*. Then retrieve the file back to PC via adb and do the comparation.

According to your code, there aren't problems and they *should* be the same.

It's likely (either) the db file itself  is broken (or) you're opening it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
private void copyDB(Context context) throws Exception{
    File destinationDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Destination/");
    File destinationFile = new File(destinationDirectory + "/myDatabase.db");
    if (!destinationDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        destinationDirectory.mkdir();
        destinationFile.createNewFile();
    }
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("my_database.db");
    if (dbFile.exists()) {
        copyFile(dbFile.getPath(), logFile.getAbsolutePath(), false);
    }
}

private boolean copyFile(String sPath, String dPath, boolean isDeleteSourceDir) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        File sourceFile = new File(sPath);
        fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        File dir = new File(dPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        File outfile = new File(dPath);
        outfile.delete();
        if (!outfile.exists()) {
            outfile.createNewFile();
        }
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        byte[] block = new byte[1000];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            fos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
        fos.close();
        if (isDeleteSourceDir) {
            deleteDirectory(new File(sPath));
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```